# Stop form submit with native javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

I need to select a form via native javascript (not jQuery) and prevent the form submission (preventDefault).

The trick is that the form does not have a name or id, and cannot be assigned one.

My HTML:

```
<div id="search">
    <form method="get">
        <input type="text" name="post"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Post">
    </form>
</div>
```

So far, I have tried to use `document.forms[0]` and `document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0]` to select the form, but the value returned is undefined.

Another possible solution is to overload the functionality of the submit button, but I did not have success with that either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `querySelector` and an event listener, it's almost like jQuery

```
document.querySelector('#search form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

note that the script has to come *after* the elements, or use a DOM ready handler, so the elements are available.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/atffm6pm/)

Comment: I tried something similar, but it tells me I cannot read property of null. I have no idea why it would be null...

Comment: It's because there is no element available, and it returns `null`, add the script after the elements in the DOM, and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

on form submit just return false.

e.g. `<form onsubmit="return false">`

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is use onsubmit event handler

```
<script>
var submitHandler = function() {
  // your code
  return false;
}
</script>

<form method="get" onsubmit="return submitHandler()">....</form>
```

or more easy

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been a bit more clear, I cannot modify the markup in any way. @adeneo's solution worked, I was on the right track I just forgot the script had to be included after the markup on the HTML page.