# Clicking form button sends Jasmine into a full page reload

Tags: angular, forms, jasmine

During a Jasmine test, I attempt to click a button to submit a form, using something like this. For a form like this :

```
<form [formGroup]="articleForm" (ngSubmit)="addArticle()">
  <div class="body">
    [...]
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="button" value="'article.add'"/>
</form>
```

This triggers the function addArticle :

```
  addArticle() {
    if(this.articleForm.valid) {
      [...]
    } else {
      this.articleForm.markAllAsTouched();
    }
  }
```

I attempt to do a test involving the clicking of this button to submit the form,

```
  it('Test', () => {
    let button = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[name^="button"]')).nativeElement;
    button.click();
  });
```

But when the test runs, Jasmine gets stuck in an infinite loop, with the following error message occuring right on the click of the button :

```
Chrome 101.0.4951.54 (Linux x86_64) ERROR
  Some of your tests did a full page reload!
```

This seems to be an error specifically tied to the clicking of that button, as if I trigger the addArticle function directly, the test proceeds as usual. The form is specifically invalid for this test, but I don't think this should be a reason for such a behaviour.

I did check if the element was indeed the correct button since it is not identified by an id and it is indeed the correct one. The component seems to function properly when I try it by hand.

What is the source of this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `input` into a `button`.

```
<button type="submit" name="button">{{ article.add }}</button>
```

And change the query:

```
let button = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button[name^="button"]')).nativeElement;
button.click();
```

Comment: Still the same behaviour.

Comment: I suspect you're most likely facing this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27514097/7365461. The form makes a `POST` request and reloads the page with stock HTML. Although, I am not sure.